# How can I know when I need another entity instead of a property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am making a project in GAE in which I have work orders which have products. These products in turn have transactions associated to them, which may happen in different days and areas. I have thought of different ways to accomplish this, which range from one extreme to the other.

The first extreme is to store all the transactions with dates and areas as one big JSON object in a JsonProperty of Product. The other one is to have an entity for each product/area, with an entity for each transaction associated to that product/area.

I don't like either of those, since the first one is at risk of reaching the 1MB limit per entity (although it's unlikely) and may require unnecessary processing, while the second one sounds terribly wasteful (way too many objects with minimal content, but they generate indices).

There are many options in between, like for instance having an entity per product/area with a smaller JSON object in them, but I don't know how to choose. Are there any key questions I can ask myself to determine when another entity is needed or when a property can be enough?

Comment: There are no clear rules, and the best technique depends on the specifics of your situation.  I have a situation where I store a list of data in a repeated pickle property and this works great for me.  Don't forget that you can compress JSON and pickle properties.  Text data is highly compressible so you can fit quite a bit into 1MB.

Comment: I know there isn't a simple answer to this, but I wanted to know if there were any key points to consider when choosing what to do. I guess I can do it either way and it will all work fine at the beginning. My problem is that I fear that what looks fine today may bring problems in a few months time.